# GUI in C++ using Visual STudio (VS) 2017 OS Win7 which components of VS2017 needed

Tags: visual-studio, user-interface, installation

I am developing a GUI in C++ for a control process. My question is which components of VS2017 I need to select during setup. I am having Win7. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Make sure you add the c++ compiler. You can disable any of the .net / CLR stuff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually, you can install the workload “**Desktop development with C++**” should meet your development requirement. Please check this: [Visual Studio 2017 workload and component IDs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/workload-and-component-ids) to know the detail description, then you can choose the required workloads or components.